# Where is the Linux kernel code that handles creation and deletion of /proc/pid/fd/# links?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Just looking for where this is handled.  I have a similar need to track open fd's without scanning the /proc system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code which fill information under `/proc/<PID>/fd` is in file [fs/proc/fd.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.5/source/fs/proc/fd.c).

I suggest to look into the function `proc_readfd_common`, which iterates over the file descriptors available for the process. This function is eventually called when directory `/proc/<PID>/fd` is read.